# using comparision operator ALL() in DB2

Tags: db2

I simple need some values depending on exactly two values , it's very simple but I don't know how to use it in DB2.

For example:

```
col1     col2
123       abc
123       def
124       ghi
123       ghj


select col1 from table where col2 =ALL('abc','def')
```

Comment: What do you suppose `ALL('abc','def')` to return? Or may be you can explain what would be the result of this query and why?

Answer (score 0):

You're using ALL wrong...

I think you want IN

```
select col1 from table where col2 IN ('abc','def')
```